# Path.Combine absolute with relative path strings

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path, filesystems

I'm trying to join a Windows path with a relative path using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

However, `Path.Combine(@"C:\blah",@"..\bling")` returns `C:\blah\..\bling` instead of `C:\bling\`.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this without writing my own relative path resolver (which shouldn't be too hard)?

Comment: We're getting different answers here..  I don't think it's a duplicate

Comment: it's duplicate, although i think Path.GetFullName is a better solution.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. But thanks for the alternate answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Path.Combine and the dot notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149312/path-combine-and-the-dot-notation)

Answer (score 90):

**What Works:**

```
string relativePath = "..\\bling.txt";
string baseDirectory = "C:\\blah\\";
string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(baseDirectory + relativePath);
```

(result: absolutePath="C:\bling.txt")

**What doesn't work**

```
string relativePath = "..\\bling.txt";
Uri baseAbsoluteUri = new Uri("C:\\blah\\");
string absolutePath = new Uri(baseAbsoluteUri, relativePath).AbsolutePath;
```

(result: absolutePath="C:/blah/bling.txt")

Comment: Yes, that is what I am insinuating with the post

Comment: Just make sure baseDirectory has the trailing \\, otherwise you end up with `C:\\blah..\\bling.txt` and that doesn't work.  In that case you can manually add them to the string or do `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, relativePath))`

Comment: Shouldn't the result of your __What Works__ section be `C:\bling.txt`?

Comment: Why does the URI-based method not work? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629990/5206621), the result is valid (and it [seems to be recognized on Windows, as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38428899/5206621)).

Answer (score 54):

Call Path.GetFullPath on the combined path http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

```
> Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"C:\blah\",@"..\bling"))
C:\bling
```

(I agree Path.Combine ought to do this by itself)

Comment: Note that this only works if the first path is an absolute path. It doesn't work for `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"..\..\blah",@"\bling"))`

Answer (score 19):

```
Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\windows\temp\..\system32")?
```

Comment: Note: should result in `c:\windows\system32`

Answer (score 5):

For windows universal apps `Path.GetFullPath()` is not available, you can use the `System.Uri` class instead:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(Path.Combine(@"C:\blah\",@"..\bling"));
 Console.WriteLine(uri.LocalPath);
```

Answer (score 5):

`Path.GetFullPath()` does not work with relative paths.

Here's the solution that works with both relative + absolute paths. It works on both Linux + Windows and it keeps the `..` as expected in the beginning of the text (at rest they will be normalized). The solution still relies on `Path.GetFullPath` to do the fix with a small workaround.

It's an extension method so use it like `text.Canonicalize()`

```
/// <summary>
///     Fixes "../.." etc
/// </summary>
public static string Canonicalize(this string path)
{
    if (path.IsAbsolutePath())
        return Path.GetFullPath(path);
    var fakeRoot = Environment.CurrentDirectory; // Gives us a cross platform full path
    var combined = Path.Combine(fakeRoot, path);
    combined = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
    return combined.RelativeTo(fakeRoot);
}
private static bool IsAbsolutePath(this string path)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
    return
        Path.IsPathRooted(path)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
private static string RelativeTo(this string filespec, string folder)
{
    var pathUri = new Uri(filespec);
    // Folders must end in a slash
    if (!folder.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())) folder += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var folderUri = new Uri(folder);
    return Uri.UnescapeDataString(folderUri.MakeRelativeUri(pathUri).ToString()
        .Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will give you exactly what you need (path does NOT have to exist for this to work)

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\blah\..\bling");
string cleanPath = di.FullName;
```

Comment: Both Path.GetFullPath() and DirectoryInfo.FullName will work on a fictitious path.  The problem is when the file actually exists, the executing process needs FileIOPermission - true for both APIs.  (see MSDN)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with Backslashes, don't forget them (neither use twice:)

```
string relativePath = "..\\bling.txt";
string baseDirectory = "C:\\blah\\";
//OR:
//string relativePath = "\\..\\bling.txt";
//string baseDirectory = "C:\\blah";
//THEN
string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(baseDirectory + relativePath);
```

Comment: There's no problem with any of the answers nor the original question, as they use the "@", we don't have to double backslashes

Answer (score 1):

To handle any absolute, relative, or URI base paths, it doesn't seem like there's one canned solution that fits all... so, I wrote one:

```
    public static String CombinePaths(String basepath, String relpath)
    {
        Stack<String> vs = new Stack<String>();

        int i;

        var s = basepath.Split('\\');
        for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] != "..")
            {
                if (s[i] != ".")
                    vs.Push(s[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                vs.Pop();
            }
        }

        var r = relpath.Split('\\');
        for (i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
        {
            if (r[i] != "..")
            {
                if (r[i] != ".")
                    vs.Push(r[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                vs.Pop();
            }
        }

        String ret = "";
        var a = vs.ToArray();
        i = a.Count() - 1;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            ret += a[i].ToString();
            ret += "\\";
            i--;
        }
        ret += a[0].ToString();

        return ret;
    }
```

Feel free to improve performance or apply whatever shortcuts apply to my answer (I don't usually work in C#; I usually write C++).