# Path.Combine and the dot notation

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory, combinations

I'm looking for something akin to `Path.Combine` method that will help me correctly combine absolute and relative paths. For example, I want

```
Path.Combine(@"c:\alpha\beta", @"..\gamma");
```

to yield `c:\alpha\gamma` instead of `c:\alpha\..\gamma` as `Path.Combine` does. Is there any easy way of accomplishing this? Needless to say, I also want to period `.` path or multiple `..` paths (e.g., `..\..\`) to work correctly.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\alpha\beta", @"..\gamma");
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(path));
```

or the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\alpha\beta", @"..\gamma");
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Console.WriteLine(info.FullName);
```

Both will output:

```
c:\alpha\gamma
```

Comment: Huh, didn't even know `GetFullPath` existed. Sexy.

Answer (score 9):

You can probably do a Path.Combine followed by a Path.GetFullPath.

Answer (score 6):

you could use a combination of 2 calls like so:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\alpha\beta", @"..\gamma");
string result = Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

And that should give you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to resolve this.

For example, this code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\alpha\beta", @"..\gamma");
Console.WriteLine(path); 
path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Will print:

```
c:\alpha\beta\..\gamma
c:\alpha\gamma
```

Answer (score 0):

But it seems GetFullPath is not always right
Try:

```
  Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"\\machine\sharea\foldera\..\shareb\folderb"));
  Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"\\machine\sharea\foldera\..\..\shareb\folderb"));
```

They output the same result, seems you cannot move it to go to a different share
The correct answer for the second one should be

\\machinea\shareb\folderb

but it gives

\\machinea\sharea\shareb\folderb

for both