# File Upload problem, file not found

Tags: asp.net

From my asp.net form, I am trying to save a picture to my SQL Database.  Problem is the File Upload button just takes the name of the file, not the full path.  When I try to save it, it says file not found.
Is there something like OpenFileDialog in webforms, as I use that for vb.net and that works excellent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Server.MapPath` method which according to MSDN

> specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

Take an example to see `Server.MapPath` in action for uploading files using asp.net:

```
'VB.net
If fileUploadControl.HasFile Then
      Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUploadControl.FileName)
      fileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") & strFileName)
End If

//C#
if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{      
      string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);

      //Save file to /images directory of web application
      FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + filename);                      
}
```

Comment: I wrote it to vb.net syntax,                                          dim filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName)  It says path is not declared.

Comment: Thanks waqas but the code you have given does not look file from chosen path.  Error is Could not find a part of the path 'D:\.Net Programs\Asp.Net\ASP.Net DB - Adv\ASP.Net DataBase Basics\images\Lalusar Lake.jpg'.  I am looking from d:\MyPics but your code goes somewhere else.

Comment: you first need to understand how paths in web application works, if you don't want to :) just skip and read the answer here i am sure it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422270/how-to-use-server-mappath-to-get-location-outside-website-folder-in-asp-net