# Specific path to a text file on an ASP.NET server application

Tags: asp.net, text-files, server.mappath

I would like to set a path to my text files which are stored in TextFiles folder. Project looks like that:

[image]

This application is already hosted on a website. I've tried almost every combinations of Server.MapPath like ("~/TextFiles/UserItemReturnMail.txt"), ("./TextFiles/UserItemReturnMail.txt"), ("\\TextFiles\\UserItemReturnMail.txt"), etc. How can I get to those files, because I have no idea now.

Comment: Did you try  System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)
and 
[How to use Server.MapPath to get location outside website folder in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422270/how-to-use-server-mappath-to-get-location-outside-website-folder-in-asp-net)

and this official :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx