# Regex to shrink Path.Combine Relative to Absolute

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have 2 file paths:

absolute:

```
/Content/assets2/otherfolder/another/this/
```

relative:

```
../../../../assets/img/logo.gif
```

when I do Path.Combine(absolute, relative) I get:

```
/Content/assets2/otherfolder/another/this/../../../../assets/img/logo.gif
```

which works fine, but what I want to get:

```
/Content/assets/img/logo.gif
```

I need a Regex or code that removes the "../" with the corresponding folder:

```
/Content/assets2/otherfolder/another/this/../../../../assets/img/logo.gif
/Content/assets2/otherfolder/another/../../../assets/img/logo.gif
/Content/assets2/otherfolder/../../assets/img/logo.gif
/Content/assets2/../assets/img/logo.gif
```

finally into:

```
/Content/assets/img/logo.gif
```

Comment: I found how:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670566/path-combine-absolute-with-relative-path-strings?rq=1

Comment: Will one of the next close voters mark as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670566/path-combine-absolute-with-relative-path-strings?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a Regex for that. Actually, I think it would be impossible to define in a reliable way in Regex. Instead, use Path.GetFullPath:

```
string combined = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
string prettyPath = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
```