# Navigating Directories using Path.Combine

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.directory

I am trying to go up a few directories and then go in to the input folder...

I have tried this

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\\..\\..\\Input\\" + filename);
```

but the value of path ends up being..

```
C:\\Users\user1\\Desktop\\ToSend\\test\\reverser\\Reverser\\bin\\Debug\\..\\\\..\\\\..\\\\Input\\\\limerick.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Path.Combine absolute with relative path strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670566/path-combine-absolute-with-relative-path-strings)

Comment: do you want to get rid of the double \ characters or the \\.. paths?

Comment: This is tangential to your actual issue, but since you are preceding the string literal with `@`, you should be using `\ `, not `\\ `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the absolute not a relative path . So you must use **GetFullPath()** instead of **Combine()**.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DirectoryInfo.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when using @ with Strings there is no need to escape \ characters, so by just using single \ slashes you can avoid the double-escaped slashes in the result.

Concerning the path question: It depends on what you want to do. If the result string is used to do some file operations using `System.IO.File.*` or to write/read from a file using `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`, the operation itself will take care of walking up the directories when detecting `\..\`, so no need to worry!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how many levels you want to remove from your path:

```
public string DirectoryGOUp(string path, int levelCount) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || levelCount < 1)
        return path;

    string upperLevel = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    if(--levelCount > 0)
        return DirectoryGOUp(upperLevel, levelCount);

    return upperLevel;
}
```

And then call it:

> var newPath = DirectoryGOUp(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),3);
>   newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, @"Input\"+filename);

Answer (score 0):

To expand on lamloumi's answer and cleanup the code:

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\..\Input", filename));
```

should produce the absolute path to your file.