# Path.Combine two relative path strings to create new relative path

Tags: c#, .net, path, filesystems

I'm trying to join two relative paths to create another **relative** (NOT absolute) path using Path.Combine.

```
string path1=@"rootDir\DirA\DirAA";
string path2=@"..\..\DirB";
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path1, path2));
//I get: rootDir\DirA\DirAA\..\..\DirB
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path1, path2)));
//I get: C:User\rootDir\DirB
```

What I actually want is

```
//rootDir\DirB
```

Is there any way to accomplish that using Path?

Comment: can you split the path string at "\" and combine the parts you want ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path.Combine absolute with relative path strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670566/path-combine-absolute-with-relative-path-strings)

Comment: @blueprogrammer No, I am looking for the relative path from the combination of two relative paths and not the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path1, path2))
    .Substring(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Length + 1);
```